# Transpose a table with keeping an ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this long table:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Personne1 | nom | Aurélie |
| Personne1 | prenom | Dupont |
| Personne1 | age | 25 |
| Personne2 | nom | Stéphane |
| Personne2 | prenom | Blanc |
| Personne2 | age | 45 |

I want to transpose it to this shape:

| col | nom | prenom | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Personne1 | Aurélie | Dupont | 25 |
| Personne2 | Stéphane | Blanc | 45 |

I tried this code in Oracle SQL developer, but it doesn't work:

```
select * 
from table as SourceTable 
pivot (max(col3) for col2 in ('nom', 'prenom', 'age'));
```

PS: the "age" column is string

Could you help please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Code you posted, as well as tags suggest that you use Oracle database. Code that follows uses Oracle.)

---

One option is to use conditional aggregation.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 'pers1', 'nom'   , 'Aurelie'  from dual union all
  3     select 'pers1', 'prenom', 'Dupont'   from dual union all
  4     select 'pers1', 'age'   , '25'       from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'pers2', 'nom'   , 'Stephane' from dual union all
  7     select 'pers2', 'prenom', 'Blanc'    from dual union all
  8     select 'pers2', 'age'   , '45'       from dual
  9    )
```

Query:

```
 10  select col1,
 11    max(case when col2 = 'nom'    then col3 end) nom,
 12    max(case when col2 = 'prenom' then col3 end) prenom,
 13    max(case when col2 = 'age'    then col3 end) age
 14  from test
 15  group by col1;

COL1  NOM      PRENOM   AGE
----- -------- -------- --------
pers1 Aurelie  Dupont   25
pers2 Stephane Blanc    45

SQL>
```

Or, pivot - as you tried:

```
 10  select *
 11  from test
 12  pivot (max(col3) for col2 in ('nom', 'prenom', 'age'));

COL1  'nom'    'prenom' 'age'
----- -------- -------- --------
pers1 Aurelie  Dupont   25
pers2 Stephane Blanc    45

SQL>
```

---

You commented that you have problems with `age` being a string; it certainly *is* a string as `COL3` contains *names* so it can't be a `NUMBER` datatype column. Though, it doesn't make any problems.

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               CHAR(5)
 COL2                                               VARCHAR2(6)
 COL3                                               VARCHAR2(8)

SQL> select * from test;

COL1  COL2   COL3
----- ------ --------
pers1 nom    Aurelie
pers1 prenom Dupont
pers1 age    25
pers2 nom    Stephane
pers2 prenom Blanc
pers2 age    45

6 rows selected.

SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  pivot (max(col3) for col2 in ('nom', 'prenom', 'age'));

COL1  'nom'    'prenom' 'age'
----- -------- -------- --------
pers1 Aurelie  Dupont   25
pers2 Stephane Blanc    45

SQL>
```

Comment: In fact, the column age is string, that's why the code gives me (null) in the age column
I updated the post @Littlefoot

Comment: It shouldn't. Have a look at edited answer which now contains a "real" table (not a CTE) and PIVOT option which returns all values, as expected.

Comment: okay thank you, it means that the aggregated function 'max' works even on string columns

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, MAX works on numbers, strings, dates, ...